# Insert record in assosiated model through console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 tables User and Member and there relation is 
In user

> has_one :member, :class_name => 'User::Member'
>   Member
>   belongs_to :user

I am trying to insert data using console and I am using this code

```
 u = User.create(
    :group         => UserGroup.find_by_slug(:members),
    :first_name    => 'abc',
    :last_name     => 'fgh',
    :company_name  => 'xyz',
    :email         => 'test@test.com',
    :password      => '123456',
    :password_confirmation => '123456'
    )   
 m = User::Member.create(
    :user           => u,
    :pricing_plan   => PricingPlan.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :state          => UserState.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :industry       => Industry.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :fy_start_month => 7
    )
```

It is throwing this error

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
>                   )  m = User::Member.create(

I am wondering what is wrong with my syntax.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to an invisible char (not whitespace). Your syntax seems to be ok, but if your  editor allows you to show invisibles (in textmate, for example, go to view > show invisibles, try to do that. It sometimes happens to me that I insert invisibles instead of whitespace.

To give you an impression what I am talking about:

This is invisibles hidden

[image]

This is invisibles shown. The invisible lozenges you do not see in normal mode cause a syntax error:

[image]

Comment: Really well looking answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `user_id` is your `foreign key` which is associated with the `users` table.
If so use following

```
m= Member.create(
    :user_id           => u.id,
    :pricing_plan   => PricingPlan.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :state          => UserState.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :industry       => Industry.order('RANDOM()').first,
    :fy_start_month => 7
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

In your User Model

```
  has_one :member
  attr_accessible :member_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :member
```

In your Member Model

```
  belongs_to :user
```

then try in your console as well as your form

```
user = User.create(
  :group         => UserGroup.find_by_slug(:members),
  :first_name    => 'abc',
  :last_name     => 'fgh',
  :company_name  => 'xyz',
  :email         => 'test@test.com',
  :password      => '123456',
  :password_confirmation => '123456'
 )
```

and

```
user.build_member(
 :pricing_plan   => PricingPlan.order('RANDOM()').first,
 :state          => UserState.order('RANDOM()').first,
 :industry       => Industry.order('RANDOM()').first,
 :fy_start_month => 7
)
```

or

```
member = Member.create(
  :user_id           => user.id,
  :pricing_plan   => PricingPlan.order('RANDOM()').first,
  :state          => UserState.order('RANDOM()').first,
  :industry       => Industry.order('RANDOM()').first,
  :fy_start_month => 7
)
```